# How find this $\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove that
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}=(-1)^{(n)}n!\dfrac{\sin{[(n+1)\cdot \mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]}}{a(x^2+a^2)^{(n+1)/2}}$$

my try:
since
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\dfrac{1}{2ai}\left(\dfrac{1}{x-ai}-\dfrac{1}{x+ai}\right),i=\sqrt{-1}$$
so
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}=\dfrac{(-1)^nn!}{2ai}\left(\dfrac{1}{(x-ai)^{n+1}}-\dfrac{1}{(x+ai)^{n+1}}\right)$$
so
let$$x=a\cot{\theta},0<\theta<\pi,$$
then
$$x\pm ai=a(\cos{\theta}\pm i\sin{\theta})/\sin{\theta}$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{(x\pm ai)^{n+1}}=\dfrac{\sin^{n+1}{\theta}}{a^{n+1}}[\cos{(n+1)\theta}\mp i\sin{(n+1)\theta}]$$
so$$\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}=(-1)^{(n)}n!\dfrac{\sin{[(n+1)\cdot \mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]}}{a(x^2+a^2)^{(n+1)/2}}$$

**Question:**

**Have other methods?**

Because this is important reslut,so I think this have other methods?  Thank you

Comment: Please do not use displaystyle math in question titles (\dfrac produces displaystyle) use \frac instead.

Comment: Why is this result important?

Comment: I'd have to say that, if a complex analysis proof exists, then it is probably better than any alternative.  In particular, induction is entirely uninformative about the origins of the formula.

Comment: @Ryan Reich, china math is asking for alternatives, not "informative" alternatives. Formula is already given. It just needs to be proven by more than one method.

Comment: @ir7 Well then, consider the proof in the question as being a derivation by induction (for computing $(1/x^2 + a^2)^{(n)}$).  The one in your answer is exactly the same, with the added unmotivated step of writing the base case in the required form so that it works.  So it's actually the same method, but with less effect and more hypotheses.  Given the form of the function, I wouldn't be surprised if there were, say, a geometric alternative that didn't go through complex analysis, and *that* would be genuinely different.

Comment: @Ryan Reich I fully agree. Please consider that the "informative" aspect of induction resides in the initial steps. Step n=0 is basically asking the solver to imagine where (1+x^2)^{-1/2} could come from? Probably trigonometry :). Then by working step n=1 one is already on his way to the "discovery".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Method

Let $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_0^\infty f(t)\operatorname{e}^{-xt}\operatorname{d}t=F(x)$$ be the Laplace transform of $f(t)$.

For $f(t)=\sin(at)u(t)$ then we have $$F(x)=\int_0^\infty \sin(at)\operatorname{e}^{-xt}\operatorname{d}t=\frac{a}{x^2+a^2}.$$

Recalling that $\mathcal{L}\{t^n f(t)\}=(-1)^n F^{(n)}(x)$ we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(-1)^nF^{(n)}(x)}{a}=\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}&=\frac{(-1)^n\mathcal{L}\{t^n f(t)\}}{a}=\frac{(-1)^n}{a}\int_0^\infty t^n \sin(at)\operatorname{e}^{-xt}\operatorname{d}t\\ 
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2ia}\left[\int_0^\infty t^n \operatorname{e}^{-(x-ia)t}\operatorname{d}t-\int_0^\infty t^n \operatorname{e}^{-(x+ia)t}\operatorname{d}t\right]\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2ia}\Gamma(n+1)\left[\frac{1}{(x-ia)^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{(x+ia)^{n+1}}\right]
\end{align}
$$ 
using the identity $\sin(at)=\frac{\operatorname{e}^{iat}-\operatorname{e}^{-iat}}{2i}$ and the Gamma Function.

For $x=a\cot{\theta},\,0<\theta<\pi,$ we have
$$
x\pm ia=\frac{a}{\sin\theta}\operatorname{e}^{\pm i\theta}={(x^2+a^2)^{1/2}}\operatorname{e}^{\pm i\theta}
$$
and finally
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2ia}\Gamma(n+1)\frac{\left[\operatorname{e}^{+i(n+1)\theta}-\operatorname{e}^{-i(n+1)\theta}\right]}{(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}=(-1)^n n!\frac{\sin\left((n+1)\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)}{a(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}.
$$

### Second Method

Observing that $$\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{x+ia}\cdot\frac{1}{x-ia}$$ and using the [general Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) $$
    (f \cdot g)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f^{(k)} g^{(n-k)} $$ with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+ia}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-ia}$ we have $$\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}(x\pm ia)^{-1}=(-1)^n n!(x\pm ia)^{-(n+1)}$$
and then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}&=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^k k!(x+ ia)^{-(k+1)}(-1)^{n-k} (n-k)!(x- ia)^{-(n-k+1)}\\
&=(-1)^n n!\sum_{k=0}^n (x+ ia)^{-(k+1)}(x- ia)^{-(n-k+1)}.
\end{align}
$$
For $x=a\cot{\theta},\,0<\theta<\pi,$ we have
$$
x\pm ia=\frac{a}{\sin\theta}\operatorname{e}^{\pm i\theta}={(x^2+a^2)^{1/2}}\operatorname{e}^{\pm i\theta}
$$
and then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}
&=(-1)^n n!\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right)^{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^n \operatorname{e}^{+i(n-2k)\theta}\\
&= (-1)^n n!\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right)^{n+2}\operatorname{e}^{+i n\theta}\frac{1-\operatorname{e}^{-2i\theta(n+1)}}{1-\operatorname{e}^{-2i\theta}}
\end{align}
$$
using the geometric sum $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} z^k = \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} $ with $z=\operatorname{e}^{-2i\theta}$.

Using the Euler's identity $\operatorname{e}^{+i\varphi}-\operatorname{e}^{-i\varphi}=2i\sin\varphi$ and multiplying and dividing by $a\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}$ we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}
&= (-1)^n n!\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right)^{n+2}\frac{a\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}}{a\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}}\frac{\operatorname{e}^{i\theta(n+1)}-\operatorname{e}^{-i\theta(n+1)}}{\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}-\operatorname{e}^{-i\theta}}\\
&=(-1)^n n!\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{a}\right)^{n+2}\frac{a}{\sin\theta}\frac{1}{a}\sin((n+1)\theta)\\
&=(-1)^n n!\frac{\sin\left((n+1)\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)}{a(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}.
\end{align}
$$

### Third Method

Let be $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{1}{1+t^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}\psi(t).$$ Observe that $$\frac{\operatorname{d}^n f(x)}{\operatorname{d}x^n}=\frac{1}{a^{n+2}}\frac{\operatorname{d}^{n+1} \psi(t)}{\operatorname{d}t^{n+1}}$$ where $\psi(t)=\arctan(t)$.

Putting $\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ the $n$th-derivative of $\psi(t)$ is
$$
\psi^{(n)}(t)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\sin^n\theta\sin(n\theta)\tag 1
$$
The existence of the derivatives follows from the analyticity of $\arctan t$ on the real line. The proof of formula (1) is by mathematical induction. Clearly, the (1) is true
for $n = 1$. Suppose the (1)is true for $n = k$; that is, suppose 
$$
\psi^{(k)}(t)=(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!\sin^k\theta\sin(k\theta)\tag 2
$$
We will show that the (1) is true for $n = k + 1$ whenever it is true for $n = k$.
Diﬀerentiating both sides of (2) with respect to $t$ and noting that $\frac{\operatorname{d} \theta}{\operatorname{d}t}=-\sin^2\theta$ gives
$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\psi^{(k)}(t)}{\operatorname{d}t}=(-1)^{k}k!\sin^{k+1}\theta[\cos\theta\sin(k\theta)+\cos(k\theta)\sin\theta]=(-1)^{k}k!\sin^{k+1}\theta\sin((k+1)\theta)$$
that is $$\psi^{(k+1)}(t)= (-1)^{k}k!\sin^{k+1}\theta\sin((k+1)\theta)$$ so the (1) is true for any $n\ge 1$.

Thus we have
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}=\frac{1}{a^{n+2}}\psi^{(n+1)}(t)=\frac{1}{a^{n+2}}(-1)^{n}n!\sin^{n+1}\theta\sin((n+1)\theta)
$$
and observing that $\frac{\sin\theta}{a}=\frac{1}{a\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$ finally we obtain
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}=(-1)^n n!\frac{\sin\left((n+1)\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)}{a(x^2+a^2)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Mathematical induction and trigonometric function relations and derivatives should do it.

I'll assume $x/a\in (0,\pi).$

Step: $n = 0$

$$\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{\sin{[\mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]}}{a(x^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$$ as
$$\sin{[\mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]} = \frac{a}{(a^2+x^2)^{1/2}}. $$

Step: $n \Rightarrow n+1$

Assume

$$\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}=(-1)^{(n)}n!\frac{\sin{[(n+1)\cdot \mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]}}{a(x^2+a^2)^{(n+1)/2}}$$

it is true, and prove

$$\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n+1)}=(-1)^{(n+1)}(n+1)!\frac{\sin{[(n+2)\cdot \mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]}}{a(x^2+a^2)^{(n+2)/2}}.$$

We now need to show:

$$\left((-1)^{(n)}n!\frac{\sin{[(n+1)\cdot \mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]}}{a(x^2+a^2)^{(n+1)/2}}\right)^\prime = (-1)^{(n+1)}(n+1)!\frac{\sin{[(n+2)\cdot \mathrm{arccot}{(x/a)}]}}{a(x^2+a^2)^{(n+2)/2}}.$$

This is due to:

$$(f/g)^\prime = (f^\prime g - fg^\prime)/g^2$$
and
$$ \sin(x+y) = \sin x\cos y + \sin y \cos x$$
and
$$ \left(\mathrm{arccot}{(x)}\right)^\prime =-\frac{1}{1+x^2}. $$

Comment: @Daniel Rust sorry I meant it as a hint. It seemed to me doable. I'll try to fill in the details, if that's what's needed. Or do you think the mathematical induction has no chance?

Comment: Got it. I'll start working on the details.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can change variables to reduce to the case $a=1$.  Second, the integral is the arctangent, so you are asking for the $(n+1)$th derivative of $\arctan(x)$.  Maple says:
$$
\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\arctan x =
\frac{1}{2}\,{2}^{n}
G^{1, 3}_{3, 3}\left({x}^{2}\, \Big\vert\,^{0, 0, 1/2}_{0, (n-1)/2, n/2}\right)
{x}^{1-n}
$$
in terms of the Meijer G-function.