# Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=\tan^{-1} \left(\frac {1+x}{1-x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=\tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac {1+x}{1-x}\right)$

My Attempt:
$$y=\tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac {1+x}{1-x}\right)$$
Put $x=\cos (\theta)$
$$y=\tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac {1+\cos (\theta)}{1-\cos (\theta)}\right)$$
$$y=\tan^{-1} \left(\dfrac {2\cos^2 \left(\dfrac {\theta}{2}\right)}{2\sin^2\left(\dfrac {\theta}{2}\right)}\right)$$
$$y=\tan^{-1} \left(\cot^2 \left(\dfrac {\theta}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844441/what-is-the-n-textth-derivative-of-fx-frac11x2)

Comment: No. This is certainly not a duplicate. Without knowing what the first derivative of the given function in OP is, it is impossible to see how the linked one is related to this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you find the *first* derivative, which is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}
$$
your question reduces to the following one:

[What is the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2844441/9464)

or more generally, this one:

[How find this $\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\right)^{(n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/622323/9464)

---

To find the first derivative, you can simply apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2844441/316404) the derivatives given are incorrect starting with the third (your fourth). Also [the accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2844444/316404) could be worked forward a little, so we provide another answer. First off,
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\left(\tan^{-1}1+\tan^{-1}x\right)\right)=\tan^{-1}1+\tan^{-1}x+[-\pi]$$
The $[-\pi]$ happens when $x>1$. So for $x\ne1$,
$$\frac d{dx}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\frac d{dx}\tan^{-1}x=\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac{-\frac12i}{x-i}+\frac{\frac12i}{x+i}$$
Then for $x\ne1$,
$$\begin{align}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)&=\frac{-\frac12i(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(x-i)^n}+\frac{\frac12i(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(x+i)^n}\\
&=\frac{\frac12i(-1)^n(n-1)!\left[(x+i)^n-(x-i)^n\right]}{(x^2+1)^n}\\
&=\frac{\frac12i(-1)^n(n-1)!}{(x^2+1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^{n-k}\left[i^k-(-i)^k\right]\\
&=\frac{\frac12i(-1)^n(n-1)!}{(x^2+1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^{n-k}i^k\left[1-(-1)^k\right]\\
&=\frac{\frac12i(-1)^n(n-1)!}{(x^2+1)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}{n\choose {2k+1}}x^{n-2k-1}i(-1)^k(2)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor}(-1)^k{n\choose {2k+1}}x^{n-2k-1}}{(x^2+1)^n}\end{align}$$
Written out,
$$\begin{array}{rl}f^{\prime}(x)&=\frac1{x^2+1}\\
f^{\prime\prime}(x)&=\frac{-(2x)}{(x^2+1)^2}\\
f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)&=\frac{2(3x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^3}\\
f^{(4)}(x)&=\frac{-6(4x^3-4x)}{(x^2+1)^4}\\
f^{(5)}(x)&=\frac{24(5x^4-10x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)^5}\\
f^{(6)}(x)&=\frac{-120(6x^5-20x^3+6x)}{(x^2+1)^6}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arctan x=z\implies x=\tan z$

$$\tan y=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4+z\right)$$

$$y=n\pi+\dfrac\pi4+\arctan x$$ where $n$ is an arbitrary integer constant so that  $-\dfrac\pi2<y<\dfrac\pi2$

$$y_1=\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac1{1+x^2}$$

$$y_1(1+x^2)=1$$

Taking $m(\ge2)$th derivative using [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

$$y_{m+1}(1+x^2)+\binom m1y_m(2x)+\binom m2 y_{m-1}(2)=0$$

Comment: How to get $n^{th}$ derivative from there?

Comment: @pi-π, Let me add

Comment: We only want an expression for $y_{n}$ , so how do we eliminate $y_{n+1}$ and $y_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$D^{n}y= D^{n-1} Dy=D^{n-1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}= D^{n-1} \frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{1}{x-i}- \frac{1}{x+i} \right)$$
The nth derivative of $(x+b)^{-1}$ is givwn as
$$D^n (x+b)^{-1}=(-1)^n n!(x+b)^{-n-1}$$ 
Using this
$$D^n y= (-1)^{(n-1)} (n-1)! ~ \Im (x-i)^{-n-2}=(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!~ (x^2+1)^{(-n-2)/2} \sin[(n+2) \tan^{-1}(1/x)].$$