# Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=e^{ax}.x^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=e^{ax}.x^3$.

My Attempt:
$$y=e^{ax}.x^3$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$
$$y_{1}=e^{ax}.3x^2+x^3.a.e^{ax}$$
Again, differentiating both sides with respect to $x$
$$y_{2}=e^{ax}.3.2.x+3x^2.a.e^{ax}+x^3.a.a.e^{ax}+a.e^{ax}.3x^2$$

Comment: What sort of result are you hoping for?  It's easy, say, to get $y^{(n)}$ at $x=0$ or something like that.  Otherwise, the answer is $(A_nx^3+B_nx^2+C_nx+D_n)e^{ax}$ and I expect one can find recursive definitions for the coefficients.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453063/find-the-nth-derivative-of-y-tan-1-left-dfrac-1x1-x-right/3453066#3453066

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{\binom n k}\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}f(x) \frac{d^k}{dx^k}g(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Leibnitz, with the power factor only having four derivatives,

$$\binom n0x^3a^ne^{ax}+\binom n13x^2a^{n-1}e^{ax}+\binom n26xa^{n-2}e^{ax}+\binom n36a^{n-3}e^{ax}.$$

After expansion,

$$((ax)^3+3n(ax)^2+3n(n-1)ax+n(n-1)(n-2))a^{n-3}e^{ax}.$$

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach by rearranging derivatives:

\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}x^3e^{ax}&=\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\frac{\mathrm d^3}{\mathrm da^3}e^{ax}\\&=\frac{\mathrm d^3}{\mathrm da^3}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}e^{ax}\\&=\frac{\mathrm d^3}{\mathrm da^3}a^ne^{ax}\\&=(a^nx^3+3na^{n-1}x^2+3n(n-1)a^{n-2}x+n(n-1)(n-2)a^{n-3})e^{ax}\end{align}